# Did the xindi attack change the timeline

Tags: star-trek

I was just wondering if the xindi attack on earth changed the timeline completely, since it's never mentioned in any other show, obviously because it was made before, but for a in universe explanation that could be why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with all that we have learned about the time wars and stuff that history in the star trek universe is likely to always be in flux or was in flux depending on your perspective (through history including your own personal experiences) and how much involvement you have with those events.